# How to use transactions with Spring Data MongoRepository?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-transactions

I have an interface extending `MongoRepository<Thing, String>` and also created a `MongoConfig` that extends `AbstractMongoClientConfiguration`. In the config, there is a `@Bean MongoTransactionManager` (no special settings used, everything is default).

Despite all this, when I try the following code:

```
    @Transactional(transactionManager = "mongoTransactionManager")
    void transactionalTest() {
      notes.save(new Thing("1"));
      fail();
      notes.save(new Thing("2"));
    }
    
    private void fail() {
      throw new RuntimeException("Failure to test transactionality.");
    }
```

I end up with "Thing 1" in my DB.
My expectation would be to see nothing there (as I marked the function with the two saves as transactional).

What am I missing?

[*] trying to follow https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-annotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I am little late for the party but I think it'd be good idea to post the answer anyway.

Its only a 2 step process:

1. Put these configurations in MongoConfig file:

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class MongoConfig {

   @Bean
   MongoTransactionManager transactionManager(MongoDatabaseFactory dbFactory) {
       return new MongoTransactionManager(dbFactory);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Put @Transactional annotation on the service method which you want to be considered as one transaction like this:

   ```
   @Transactional
   void transactionalTest() {
       notes.save(new Thing("1"));
       fail();
       notes.save(new Thing("2"));
   }

   private void fail() {
       throw new RuntimeException("Failure to test transactionality.");
   }


   private void fail() {
       throw new RuntimeException("Failure to test transactionality.");
   }
   ```

- Code level changes are done. Now we need to check the server configurations.

1. Go to mongo configuration file (I used this method to configure my brew installed mongodb: https://silvae86.github.io/2021/03/04/migrate-mongodb-from-single-to-replicaset/)

Answer (score 0):

Add the below attribute for handling exception :

```
@Transactional(rollbackOn = RuntimeException.class)
```

For more details, Check - [Here](https://blog.pchudzik.com/201911/transactional-errors/)

Comment: The documentation says it is called `rollbackFor`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html

Comment: I see that I misled you a bit. I slightly modified the example, see `fail`. This way the following documentation applies: "By default, a transaction will be rolling back on RuntimeException" (the same is stated on the page you linked).